# Academic phrase / alternative phrase for "neatly arranged" or "orderly manner"

Tags: phrase-requests

I am asking for an academic or alternative formal phrase for:

The findings and analyses should be "arranged in an orderly and clear form" on papers or for a presentation.

I found the following:
 - orderly manner
 - transparent
 - neatly arranged

I assume that there are more formal and common alternative expressions
to express in short words the necessary of a good structure and clarity in preparing a report, reviewing something, or for presentation.

Comment: Well organized and clearly presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that there are more formal and common alternative expressions
> to express in short words the necessary of a good structure and
> clarity in preparing a report.

## Logically and succinctly expressed.

Logically - because the paper needs to follow a logical progression through the various arguments or expositions etc.

[Succinctly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/succinct):

> (especially of something written or spoken) briefly and clearly
> expressed. --OLD

Comment: It´s quite informative, but i still suppose that there are more expressions and I hope to reach more than one response to my posting here.